# How to quick-access the root of my website using window.open()?

Tags: javascript, html, url, window.open

Let's say I have a page located here in my website:

- `mywebiste.com/section1/slideshow/main/example.html`

I'd like to use `window.open()` to access these pages in my website:

- `mywebsite.com/section2/index.html`
- `mywebsite.com/section2/article1/gallery.html`
- `mywebsite.com/login.php`

These are just random examples, but I'm trying to point out that they are very far away from the `example.html` page, and I would have to use a lot of `../` and as such ending up with very long *(and confusing)* URLs.

I thought that there should be a way to directly access the root of the website, but still using relative URLs. (Like if a shortcut `.../` or `root/` existed and that could redirect you to the root).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Just to preface with a `/` *should* work.

```
window.open('/section2/index.html', ...); // etc
```

Comment: Yes, but oddly enough, it doesn't seem to move. I'm using `_parent` instead of `_self` since the page is loaded in an iframe, though I don't think that might be the issue.

Comment: I mean, the link does not open any page at all.

Comment: link? Why are you using javascript to open a link? Can't you use `target="_blank"` on the `a` tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107041/discussion-between-yonic-and-neal).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.origin` in JavaScript which returns the protocol, hostname and port.

For instance:

```
window.open(window.location.origin + '/other-folder/index.html');
```

This is not IE compatible, but you can try this polyfill: http://tosbourn.com/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/